# Implementing Haskell#lines

Tags: haskell, reinventing-the-wheel

[Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/modules#loading-modules) shows the `lines` function:

> It takes a string and returns every line of that string in a separate list.

Example:

> ```
> >lines' "HELLO\nWORLD\nHOWAREYOU"
> ["HELLO","WORLD","HOWAREYOU"]
> ```

Here's my implementation:

```
lines' :: String -> [String]
lines' [] = []
lines' xs = lines'' xs []
             where lines'' [] ys = ys : []
                   lines'' (x:xs) ys 
                     |  x == '\n' = ys : lines'' xs []
                     | otherwise  = lines'' xs (ys ++ [x])
```

Please critique it. Also, when using an `accumulator` value (such as `ys` in `lines''`), I don't know how to use the `:` function instead of `++`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. What happens when a string ends in a newline? `lines "\n"` ⇒ `[""]`, but `lines' "\n"` ⇒ `["", ""]`.
2. `ys` could have a more informative name. `line`?
3. <del>When you find yourself wanting to add new items to the end of a list, consider keeping the list in reverse order, adding items to the front and reversing it when it's done. This avoids needing to use `++`.</del> ("Done" is a fuzzy concept when working lazily with infinite lists.)
4. ...but when reinventing the wheel, you needn't reinvent the axle and bearings as well. There is a Prelude function that will parse one line from a string: `break`. If you use that, you need only handle recursing on the remainder. This is [how `lines` is really implemented](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/Data-List.html#line-1056).

   ```
   lines s         =  let (l, s') = break (== '\n') s
                      in  l : case s' of
                                   []      -> []
                                   (_:s'') -> lines s''
   ```

Comment: thanks, Anonymous. Excellent suggestions for improvement. Would you implement #1 by simply adding that special case `lines' "\n" = [""]`?

Comment: No, because it wouldn't cover other strings ending in newlines (e.g. `lines "a\n"` ⇒ `["a"]`), and because it can be done without a special case by recursing appropriately.