# Implementing Haskell#break

Tags: haskell, reinventing-the-wheel

[Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/modules#loading-modules) demonstrates the `break` function:

> breaks it when the predicate is first true.

Example:

```
-- ghci> break (==4) [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]  
-- ([1,2,3],[4,5,6,7])
```

Here's my code:

```
break' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
break' _ [] = ([], [])
break' f ys = break'' f ys []
               where break'' _ [] acc = (reverse acc, [])
                     break'' g xxs@(x:xs) acc 
                        | g x       = (reverse acc, xxs)
                        | otherwise = break'' g xs (x:acc)
```

I used the `reverse` rather than use the `++` function due to [@Anonymous's](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/42364/anonymous) helpful advice on my implementation of [lines](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/49603/31595).

Please review it.

Answer (score 3):

The first `[]` case is unnecessary, since `break''` already handles empty lists.

`g` is unnecessary, since `f` is in scope.

`break''` has two nearly identical base cases, which could be combined into one (you may need to use `head` and `tail` instead of pattern-matching). That's a line shorter but IMO no clearer.

My previous advice to reverse the accumulator contained a subtle flaw: it needs to find the boundary before it returns anything, so it's not lazy enough. (This is a subtlety of lazy data structures; if you don't understand it yet, don't worry about it.) This occasionally matters in cases like this:

```
let (a, b) = break (==' ') $ "abc" ++ undefined in head a
```

[The actual implementation](http://git.haskell.org/ghc.git/blob/HEAD:/libraries/base/GHC/List.lhs#l480) avoids this by simply adding `x` to the result of the recursive call, without using an accumulator:

```
break _ xs@[]           =  (xs, xs)
break p xs@(x:xs')
           | p x        =  ([],xs)
           | otherwise  =  let (ys,zs) = break p xs' in (x:ys,zs)
```